# Regex to match everything from url but without subdomain

Tags: php, regex

i have the regex `~[^\.]*\.[a-z]{3}$~` which matches test.net for following url over preg_match:

```
url.test.net
```

Now i need a regex which matches test.net for the following url:

```
p59027s1628.url.test.net
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Your regex is already matching `test.net` in `p59027s1628.url.test.net`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=url.).*$
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/nX4cQ2/3)

Explaining:

```
(?<=url.)       # looks for "url." - without taking it
.*$             # matches everything till the end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you wanted to write this way:
https://regex101.com/r/nX4cQ2/2
`(?<=\.)([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$`

Comment: @zolo. I don't think so. Anyways, thank you, I've edited to match the correct output.

Comment: I really not mean to disturb you, but your regexp will work ONLY with this type of domain name. Then it would be enough to use only "test.net" as it will perfectly match the "test.net" from that url.

Comment: @zolo. Maybe you're right, but also maybe `url.` will be a constant, or even a parameter in a function... just maybe

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex  :

```
[^.]+\.[a-z]*\.[a-z]{3}$
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/bV7tM6/1

Or more precise you can use following regex:

```
(?:[a-z]*\.){2}[a-z]{3}$
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/bV7tM6/2